Structure of the headline "Olympics organizers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows."
I've bumped into this newspaper's front page. I don't want to discuss politics but the structure of the sentence.




Olympics organizers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows.
—New York Post

I understand the general meaning of the sentence, but its structure feels like it's just a set of randomly ordered words. It feels to me like it's two sentences joined with the conjunction 'over' (in the meaning of 'while'). But in this case 'scramble as furor' makes no sense and feels like an idiom I don't get. It also would make sense if 'over' was a preposition, meaning the furor is over the (woke) blasphemy, but in this case the verb 'grows' is  odd in the sentence structure. Or the 'grows' is suddenly a plural noun, and 'furor' is over the 'grows'.
So I would like a sort of a syntactic analysis in the explaining of the sentence . Again, no politics, I often experience this kind of frustration reading tweets and newspaper headlines all over the political spectre.

Is the front page also called  a cover page now?

Are sure you mean "political spectre"? This is a very rare term I do not know (political spectre,poilitical spectrum, and a very usual and similarly sounding one is "political spectrum" (no bogeyman connotations).

"As" is meaning "while", introducing an event happening at the same time. "As" has a lot of meanings/functions, but this is a common one (conjunction 5)

Per @StuartF, compare the sentence to The fishermen prepared their nets as a tentative sun climbed into a murky sky.

... or Holidaymakers panic as fear over new COVID outbreak grows. Here, 'as' is a conjunction, signalling both simultaneity and reason (N₁ V₁ at the same time as / because N₂ V₂). // The present simple is far more common in headlines than in normal conversation. // 'Scramble' here is metaphorical; compare 'rush around like headless chickens'.

The furor was over woke blasphemy. The furor grew. The  Olympics organisers scrambled in reaction to the furor.

Little note - in British English it would be 'furore' and pronounced in the Italian way.

Why was the front page image deleted? It wasn't vulgar or irrelevant,  it actually helped understand the "woke blasphemy" part and consequently what the furore was about. You need to understand the newspaper headline in order to parse it.

Note, "headlinese" often creates constructions that are difficult to make sense of, sometimes famously so. It's not just you.

@AndyBonner The structure is pretty common in English...

Newspaper headlines, and to a more limited extent TV news headlines have a syntax all of their own, and very frequently take several passes for a native speaker to understand; possibly by design - if you see a stack of newspapers on a stand, and can't understand the headline at first glance, it makes you stop and re-read it, making you more likely to purchase.

@MikeB Yes, sometimes but not in this case that has standard grammar. I gve several examples in my answer.

@Lambie  "Standard grammar" ?? Certainly not "Standard usage". The construction of this headline is much too terse for normal prose, as your own answer (and all of the others) demonstrates.

@MikeB Take a look at my answer: Happiness over the outcome disappeared. Anger over the waste dissapated. Those are standard grammar.

For the record: despite the resemblance to the Last Supper, it was intended to be "a nod to a pagan celebration featuring Dionysus, the Greek god of fertility, wine and revelry"; see: https://eu.usatoday.com/story/sports/olympics/2024/07/29/paris-last-supper-olympics-dionysus/74586328007/

I've been editing news stories, designing newspaper pages and otherwise existing in this professional context for almost 25 years. This sentence (a "deck", strictly speaking) doesn't strike me as particularly unusual.

Olympics organizers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows



First, the core of the sentence: its subject and its verb.

organizers scramble

In this usage, scramble is, as Merriam-Webster describes it, an intransitive verb meaning "to move with urgency or panic" (definition 1).

But which organizers?

Olympics organizers scramble

Here, Olympics is an adjective describing the named organizers as those of the Paris Games.

What are the circumstances causing these organizers to scramble?

Olympics organizers scramble as ______

The remainder of the sentence is an adverbial clause beginning with the subordinating conjunction as.
I'll discuss that clause separately.


An adverbial clause, like any other dependent clause, contains its own subject and verb.
In this example, the clause (minus the conjunction as which introduced it) is:

furor over woke blasphemy grows

At its most basic, this clause says:

furor grows

where furor has the meaning of "an outburst of public excitement or indignation" (definition 4b).

What kind of furor? It's about something in particular.
The writer describes the furor with a prepositional phrase, beginning with the preposition over:

furor over ______ grows

where over is "used as a function word to indicate the object of an expressed or implied occupation, activity, or concern" (entry 2, definition 7b).

The remaining words, then, describe the reason for the controversy (the furor).
Some observers believe one scene of the Games' opening ceremony was disrespectful of their religious beliefs and history.
Put differently, they considered it a type of blasphemy:

furor over ______ blasphemy grows

where blasphemy is defined as "irreverence toward something considered sacred or inviolable" (definition 2).

To call something blasphemous (blasphemous is the adjectival form of blasphemy, making use of the -ous suffix) is a serious charge.
What kind of blasphemy was it?

furor over woke blasphemy grows

You asked in your question to avoid politics, so I'll avoid attempting to add my own thoughts here.
Instead, I'll point you to an assortment of pieces attempting to define this adjective in the current American political context:

https://www.politifact.com/article/2023/mar/07/what-does-it-mean-to-be-woke/
https://www.kpbs.org/news/local/2022/03/11/lets-talk-about-it-what-does-woke-actually-mean
https://www.vox.com/culture/21437879/stay-woke-wokeness-history-origin-evolution-controversy
https://www.poynter.org/fact-checking/2023/what-does-woke-mean-definition/
https://www.motherjones.com/mojo-wire/2022/12/desantis-ron-woke-florida-officials/

Presumably, this portion of the ceremony is being described as such because the performers were in drag.


Now that we've explored the adverbial clause in detail, let's resume examining the entire sentence:

Olympics organizers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows

In other words:

People thought part of a performance was "woke" and offensive to their religion ("woke blasphemy").
That led to an increasing amount of criticism ("furor over woke blasphemy grows").
That, in turn, caused the organizers of the Olympic Games (where the performance took place) to panic ("Olympics organizers scramble").


[Olympics organisers scramble] as [furor over woke blasphemy grows].
[Modifier + Subject + Predicate] + as + [Subject + Modifier + Predicate]
Grows is a verb and is the predicate of the subordinate clause.
The preposition phrase
over woke blasphemy modifies the subject furor.

Sample:
The parse is this:

Olympics organisers scramble// as furor /over woke blasphemy/ grows.

Paraphrase: Olympics organisers scramble at the same time that furor over woke blasphemy grows.

as furor over woke blasphemy grows


Other similar examples of this pattern:

as understanding about retrograde amnesia disappeared

as happiness over winning the competition dissipated


So, we say emotions or opinions caused over something thing. Here, furor over some thing. One can also say: furor about something.
If you remove the as,  there is a grammatical full sentence with subject verb and object:

Furor over woke blasphemy grows.
Happiness over the outcome disappeared.

as is a conjunction in the phrase. It means at the same time as.
over is just a preposition that mean about or with regard to. It does join "organizers scramble" to "furor over woke blasphemy grows"

He was angry over the situation that developed after the boxing match.


"at the same time that" is a bit off -- the implication is closer to "due to the concurrent", but admittedly that is just implied.

@Yakk as  at the same time that something else happened. The stock market crashed as [at the same time that]  the country went to hell.

My point is, "Bob dropped a rock as the sun rose" would be a joke headline if the sun rising was completely unconnected (other than time) to Bob dropping the rock; there is a strong implication in the "as" connecting them to have more meaning beyond "at the same time as".

"as" is a headline writer's shorthand, it says that two things are happening, and implies without actually saying so that they would like you to think the two things are connected. "Riots in Southport as Temperatures Reach 30°C" is a classic example. Similar: "Record Number of Migrants Arrive as Minister Basks in the Sun".

Moreover, "Furor Grows" is headline writer's shorthand for "More and more journalists are picking up this story".

@MichaelKay So what? It is still grammatical English without any shortcut(s) and I have explained it. No need to try and parse its "ideology".

Headlines have conventions of their own, in particular there is very little context to help you, and to understand their meaning I think you often have to be aware of the conventions adopted by headline-writers.

@MichaelKay The OP said: "[the] structure feels like it's just a set of randomly ordered words". I know all about headlinese. Not all headlines are the same. Some drop words or determiners, others do not. The OP was wondering here about the grammar, which happens to be completely standard.

Standard but terse and with very little redundancy, which is why the OP was having difficulty.

I'm going to just build up the final headline from the simplest parts. I'll explain the evolving meaning as we go. Hopefully this will provide some visualization for the parse tree of the headline.

Olympics organisers scramble.

The Olympics organisers are engaging in quick and hurried action (for some reason).

Olympics organisers scramble as furor grows.

The organisers are scrambling at the same time that a furor (i.e., an angry outcry or feeling from the public) is growing ("grows" is the singular verb attached to the subject "furor"). Not only are they scrambling at the same time that the furor is getting worse, they are doing so in response to or because of that furor (this is implied by the clipped headline style that uses "as" to link two different statements).

Olympics organisers scramble as furor over blasphemy grows.

The furor they are responding to has to do with blasphemy (of some kind).

Olympics organisers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows.

The blasphemy has to do with wokeness. (I can't tell what this means from the headline alone. It could be that someone said "wokeness is bad" or "wokeness is good"
So the final meaning is: a furor is growing, regarding an instance of blasphemy about wokeness issues; in response to that, the Olympics organisers are engaged in hurried and confused activity.
And maybe the parse tree can be visualized like this:

[[Olympics [organisers]] scramble] as [[[furor] over [woke [blasphemy]]] grows].


In this context, it's not blasphemy about wokeness, it's blasphemy that is woke.

No!  The blasphemy is about a drag representation of The Last Supper.  The wokeness is a response to the blasphemy accusation.

@Chenmunka The ceremony contained an image that evoked the Last Supper, but contains drag queens in place of the apostles. Diversity is "woke", and it's considered blasphemy to mock the Last Supper.

I think that should parse as [[woke] blasphemy], not [woke [blasphemy]].

@Barmar Based on the assumption that it was in reference to the Last Supper.  Wrong deity, wrong pantheon.

@LorenPechtel That's why I said "evoked". The creator says it was based on something from ancient Greece, but viewers saw what they wanted to see.

And it's hardly an unreasonable expectation. This was in the Louvre, and the Last Supper is a famous painting there.

@Barmar A quick Google informs me Leonardo's Last Supper is located in Milan.

@KenY-N Thanks. I guess lots of people made the same incorrect assumption as me.

Prepositional phrase "over woke blasphemy" is an adjunct describing the basis for the "furor".
Compare:

Anger over vodka tax causes widespread revolt

over can sometimes be used as a synonym for "about".

Government officials scramble as anger over vodka tax spreads


The primary difficulty is that the newspaper layout has confused the parsing.
It has been printed to suggest:
Olympics organizers, scramble as furor over, woke blasphemy grows.

"scramble as furor over" is just a random collection of words, and "woke blasphemy grows" isn't much better.
That's why it feels like a string of random words: the provided parsing didn't work.
Then you had a second shot at it, as:
Olympics organizers scramble as furor over woke blasphemy grows.

Which was only marginally better, because you were still confused. But if the sentence was spoken, you wouldn't have had a problem, because it would be spoken as
Olympics organizers scramble, as furor over woke blasphemy grows.

Lacking the critical pause/comma after "scramble", the implied parsing is incorrect, and in this case you have to read all the way to the end of the sentence to resolve the ambiguity. And as you proceed through the sentence, your preferred/expected English parsing turns out to be worse and worse.
The "wrong" parsing is preferred because we prefer to attach the new word to the previous word when possible.
When you get to the end of the sentence, you start again, work out what it means, and it still feels wrong. But if feels wrong because it was unusual, and made more difficult by the print layout and lack of punctuation.
That's why we use punctuation.
Note: in a posting regarding how layout affects understanding, I've used a markup that preserves layout (it's called a 'code' markup). A bot on this site tried to change the markup, because "layout preservation" makes it impossible to wrap text like a newspaper headline does. Stack Exchange bots make the same kind of choices that newspaper editors do, and for the same reasons.

"That's why we use punctuation." – Obligatory "Let's eat, grandma" reference.

@david I would write Bob talks on the phone  while Sarah prepares dinner.  I would not put a comma after the word phone.  The real issue here is the use of headlinese English. Generally, headlines do not use punctuation. Headlines are deliberately shortened and simplified to be as concise as possible, often at the expense of clarity. Minimizing articles, adjectives, and verbs, using abbreviations, nicknames, etc. Also, headlines are generally composed on short notice in response to ongoing events, so they're often rushed at the last minute.

Code markup is inaccessible for anyone whose eyesight is impaired and relies on a screen reader. Code markup should be reserved for writing code. “Code markup should not be used for any non-code elements. This includes using it for emphasis, for tables, or other non-code usage" The layout is still preserved if you use bold, italics and speech marks. The "bot" means the edit was approved by two users, it is a place holder for anonymous user.
